# Complete Schema Definition for createUiDefinition for Azure Marketplace

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

Based on the **Azure Marketplace Sample** for Simple Linux VM in the Azure Quickstart template on GitHub (https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/marketplace-samples/simple-Linux-VM), the complete schema definition of the **createUDefinition**  can be found on https://github.com/azure/azure-portal-createuidefinition.

However, the 2nd link above results in **404 NOT FOUND** as shown below:
[image]

Does anyone know the correct link to the **Complete Schema Definition** for **createUDefinition** for Azure Marketplace?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Thank you for asking this.  Too bad about the answer.

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT EDIT* Apparently this feature isn't ready yet. If you look at the version on the shcema template I posted you can see it is version 0.0.1-preview. Why they made an announcement stating publication of solution templates is ready when it explicitly relies on a 0.0.1-preview item is beyond me. The word I'm getting from Microsoft is that the current process is basically manual while they get the bugs out (understandable). The marketplace team is effectively working 1 on 1 with developers to publish things as part of this process (which is rather awesome). 
In Summary there is no complete definition yet. Microsoft's Azure marketing team basically announced a feature to be ready at least a year before their Azure engineering dept had a chance to make a useful prototype (which is atrocious). The reason the docs aren't there is because Microsoft has a current trend of not documenting anything until after it's been in the wild long enough for the early adopters to debug and blog about (document) it for them. There won't be an actual answer with the complete schema for probably another few months.

*EDIT* It appears this is extremely similar to what the OP already found. I need this for work, so I'll update this with better info as I find it.

The link is basically an example showing how to use the CreateUiDefinition.json file. The actual schema is on that page (for now). 
The "code" feature isn't working for me at the moment. Here is a snip from the only place I can find anything on this topic that is relevant: [Simple-Windows-VM Template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/marketplace-samples/simple-windows-vm)

[image: Schema Image]

Comment: In case it isn't clear in my post, using ctrl-k isn't working in my browser. Neither is the 4 spaces thing. It keeps throwing a malformed code error when I try to post.

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. However, I am looking for the complete schema definition. The one you added is seems to be the basic outline and there should be a complete one but it turns out to be a broken link.

Comment: @juvchan - I noticed. The link I posted is basically the windows vm version of the same link you found the broken link on. I opened a support ticket with Microsoft specifically asking this question, and the follow up of how to cert test templates so they can be published. I'll post what ever I get from them.

Answer (score 0):

At least, there is the commplete schema definition for the preview version here: [azure-resource-manager-schemas](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/tree/master/schemas/0.1.2-preview)